# Choose specific values from a column for a new table

Tags: r, subset

It may be an easy question. But I am a new user of r. 
Here is my dataframe.
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tf3vF.png)

I have this data for 104 countries. I want to split the table into two tables. Where one table will include years (1990 and 1995) and the other table will include years(2000 and 2005). 
I tried this
`new_table <- subset(data_frame, years == 'X1990' & years == 'X1995' )`

It didn't give me an error but the tables appeared with no values in it!

Comment: I think you need `%in%` i.e. `subset(data_frame, years %in% c("X1990", "X1995"))`

Comment: the reason is you are subsetting where  years == 'X1990' & years == 'X1995'. Instead try new_table <- subset(data_frame, years == 'X1990') and new_table2 <- subset(data_frame, years == 'X1995' )

Comment: @user2510479 Based on the original question, the two tables are data with years 1990 or 1995, and data with 2000 or 2005, so akrun's and Feng's solutions are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `years == 'X1990' | years == 'X1995'`. A OR function, not AND.

Comment: This will give a subset where the year is either 1990 or 1995 but the requirement is two tables, one for each year

Comment: one table will include years (1990 and 1995)， the other table will include years(2000 and 2005). Each table contains two years...@user2510479